# Using Amazon Webservices in android application

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I have read on net tutorials that cloud can be used for storing data.So i wanted to ask that whether sql server 2005 table data be stored in amazon cloud.Can anyone give me the sample code to store data from sql server in amazon and retrieve it in android application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon gives you a server instance with the operating system specified by you. you can technically, install anything on it and host that.

1. What you should technically do is to take an instance of your desired specification from Amazon.
2. Write a simple web application (I would do a java webapp. For sure you can go for the same as you already are doing Android programming.) with connectivity to your DB and that has controllers to run your SQL queries and returns the values.

Here is some example code. This uses Spring just so you know. You can use plain MVC as well if you want do it simple to start with.

```
    @RequestMapping ( value = "runquery" , method = RequestMethod.GET )
@ResponseBody
public void runQuery()
{

    Statement lStatement        = null;
    Connection lConnection      = null;
    ResultSet lResultSet        = null;
    try
    {
        lConnection = DBAccess.getConnection();
        lStatement  = lConnection.createStatement();
        lResultSet  =  lStatement.executeQuery( "select * from table" );

        while ( lResultSet.next() )
         {
            mLogger.info("The result set is : "+lResultSet.toString());
         }

    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        mLogger.error("Exception occurred while trying to runQuery : "+e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        DBAccess.closeResultSet( lResultSet );
        DBAccess.closeStatement( lStatement );
        DBAccess.closeDBConnection( lConnection );
    }

}
```